# Failed to install apk on ICS 4.03 emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adb

I can't install my apk on a API 4.0.3 ADV device from eclipse.

Here the **data**:

**IDE** Eclipse 3.6.2

**Device**
Android 4.0.3 (API 15) Rev 2
WVGA800
Density 160
Heap 48
RAM 512 (tried 1024 as well)

I got this **error**:

```
Failed to install test.apk on device 'emulator-5554': EOF
[2012-02-28 09:18:11 - test] java.io.IOException: EOF
[2012-02-28 09:18:11 - test] Launch canceled!*
```

And the device disappeared from the DDMS screen.

**NOTE**: if I change WVGA800 to HVGA everything works!

Any solution to this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use adb command to install apk files to emulator/devices

```
adb install test.apk
```

set environmental varaible before using adb

if you are using linux use this command

```
export PATH=$PATH{}:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
```

or you can use relative path of the command like this

```
/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb install test.apk
```